# Passing offset inside custom regression function

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm

I am trying to create a custom regression function for running multiple models (simplified here for detail). However, I am unable to pass an offset into this function. I am aware that this can be done inside of a formula but for this particular use case it must be an optional parameter.

Here is what I have:

```
fit_glm <- function(formula, df, 
                    model_offset = NULL,
                    family = quasipoisson){
  
  fit <- glm(formula, data = df,
             offset = model_offset,
             family = family)
  
  return(fit)
}

data(mtcars)

fit_glm(mpg ~ hp, df = mtcars)
```

Whenever I run this I am met with `Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'model_offset' not found`. Perhaps I am missing something very simple.

Performing this call using:

```
glm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, family = quasipoisson, offset = NULL)
```

Works perfectly fine. I want this method to be possible for running models with and without an offset, currently neither work.

Any help is much appreicated, tia

Comment: A [mre] would help

Comment: Try using `offset = eval(model_offset)` in the glm call, and passing in e.g. `model_offset = quote(NULL)`. Stuff like this is a known PITA for lm and friends.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've added an example. Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work.